# How to export my android app database to .db file and then import it to another app

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

Here is my database class,

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "MY_DB");

        String CREATE_MY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + "MY_DB" + "("
            + KEY_USER_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_GENDER + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT " + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_MY_TABLE);
    }
}
```

Then I have assigned some data to it. Now I am trying to export this into a database file as "MY_DB.db" or "MY_DB.sqlite", but not as "MY_DB.csv".

Then what should I do?

Comment: you can pick the database file directly from your app's private storage. If I'm right, it is stored as .sqlite file

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLnVhgYdVd8 Visit this video

Comment: Thanks @Md.SajedulKarim, It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve your database by using this adb command :
`adb exec-out run-as {packageName} cat databases/{dbName} > {dbName}`

You can probably put your .sqlite file into the private storage with the same command, even if I never tried personally. I only had the need to retrieve it from the app to check some tables.